# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE не срабатывает при несовпадающих названиях полей в исходной и целевой таблицах

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `marital_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `anketa` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `marital_status_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Почему не работает вставка выбранного значения со следующим кодом:

```sql
INSERT INTO `contacts` (`marital_status`) 
    SELECT `marital_status_id` 
    FROM `anketa` 
    WHERE `id`=215409 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `marital_status` = VALUES(`marital_status`)
```

И чем по смыслу отличается такой вариант кода (разница в самой концовке, тоже не срабатывает):

```sql
INSERT INTO `contacts` (`marital_status`) 
    SELECT `marital_status_id` 
    FROM `anketa` 
    WHERE `id`=215409 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `marital_status` = `marital_status_id`";
```

Имеющиеся в документации пояснения не помогают. Что я не учёл?

P.S. нашел ошибку - "нечаянно" удалил из запроса уникальное поле (id) - после его возвращения заработало:

```sql
INSERT INTO `contacts` (`id`, `marital_status`) 
    SELECT `id`, `marital_status_id` 
    FROM `anketa` 
    WHERE `id`=215409 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `id` = VALUES(`id`), 
    `marital_status` = VALUES(`marital_status`)
```

Comment: Вы уверены что запрос вообще выполняется без ошибок?

Comment: дублированными считаются строки у которых совпали уникальные индексы или первичные ключи

Comment: @InDevX получаю ответ: 
    `$result: Resource id #85
$row: Array
(
    [marital_status_id] => 1
)

$result: 1 `
т.е. запрос 
`if (!($result = mysql_query($sql))) {
    report_mysql_error("Не могу выполнить запрос ", $sql, true);`
выполняется и ошибки не выводятся

Comment: @Grundy т.е. id, который имеется в обеих таблицах, должен входить в состав выборки и вставки?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` плевать хотел с высокой колокольни на имена полей. Его интересует только нарушение ограничения уникальности. Всё остальное надо разруливать тебе. В частности - забыть на всю оставшуюся жизнь дефолты и везде аккуратно ручками прописывать по отдельности все поля , не забывая снабжать их алиасами таблиц.

Comment: *Почему не работает вставка выбранного значения со следующим кодом* Что именно наблюдается? присвоение неверного значения? сообщение об ошибке? И давайте без PHP-кода и шаблонов, предметно - вот структура, было вот, запрос вот, результат вот, хотя должен быть вот.

Comment: @Akina значение целевого поля остается NULL, хотя в таблице выборки оно равно 1

Comment: Ну тогда в студию - CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц, пример данных как INSERT INTO, текст запроса после всех подстановок и требуемый конечный результат.

Comment: @Akina нашел косяк - не добавил в запрос первичный ключ (id). Можете пояснить в каких случаях разные варианты запроса INSERT INTO (приведены в топике, отличаются концовкой) - с добавленным ключом или уникальным полем - дадут разный результат? в моем случае оба результата оказались одинаковы

Comment: *... текст запроса **после всех подстановок ... без PHP-кода и шаблонов** ...*

Comment: @Akina не вполне понял, что значит "без шаблонов" (в своем коде таких не опознал), но весь код поправил - удалил php, объединил в один запрос. вопрос - во втором предложении топика

Comment: Теперь добавьте в вопрос ещё CREATE TABLE для таблицы.

Answer (score 4):

Почему `` INSERT INTO `contacts` (`id`, `marital_status`) ... `` может работать, а `` INSERT INTO `contacts` (`marital_status`) ... `` нет?

Предположение только одно. `id` является NOT NULL полем, у которого не указано DEFAULT значение (в т.ч. автогенерируемое). Это и приводит к ошибке.

---

Почему `` INSERT INTO `contacts` (`id`, `marital_status`) ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... `` может и вставлять, и обновлять, а `` INSERT INTO `contacts` (`marital_status`) ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... `` всегда вставляет?

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` интересует только нарушение ограничения уникальности.

Если второй вариант не приводит к ошибке, значит, поле `id` объявлено как AUTO_INCREMENT, и для него генерируется уникальное значение.  Поскольку у `ODKU` прописано `` UPDATE `marital_status` = VALUES(`marital_status`) ``, то это поле не уникально. Итого - никакого дублирования в принципе нет, и у `ODKU` нет оснований для срабатывания и обновления.

---

> чем по смыслу отличается такой вариант кода

В первом варианте `` `marital_status` = VALUES(`marital_status`) `` полю при обновлении присваивается то значение, которое было бы в него вставлено, если бы не было ошибки дублирования.

Во втором варианте `` `marital_status` = `marital_status_id` `` полю просто присваивается значение из другого поля той же записи.

> `marital_status_id` и `marital_status` - поля из разных таблиц – Simply One

В таком случае этот вариант синтаксически некорректен. В `ODKU` нельзя ссылаться на поля таблицы-источника - они уже недоступны. `ODKU` - это фактически триггер. Ссылаться можно только на поля обновляемой таблицы - если брать аналогию с триггером, то просто поле есть поле из `OLD`, а поле-аргумент функции `VALUES()` - поле из `NEW`.

Comment: на основной вопрос топика я нашел подсказку в ответе  @Grundy.
к вам вопрос был тот, который во втором предложении топика. дело осложнило то, что пока правил по вашему требованию код, добавил в него по ошибке и `id`, которого не было в ошибочном коде. заметил - удалил для сохранения истории вопроса

Comment: ценю ваши просветительские усилия, но, каюсь, я переоценил дедуктивные способности читателей (или желание их проявлять) и решил было, что по тексту запросов можно было понять, что `marital_status_id` и `marital_status` - поля из разных таблиц. поэтому, думаю, ваш ответ на второй вопрос не корректен (по большей части, моя вина). добавил команды CREATE TABLE

Comment: @SimplyOne Добавил пояснение.

Comment: пояснение звучит убедительно, однако команда 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `id` = VALUES(`id`), 
    `marital_status` = `marital_status_id`
выполняется так же успешно, как и в варианте с VALUES(`marital_status`)

Comment: @SimplyOne Это потому, что в обеих таблицах `id` является первичным ключом. Представь, что в таблице-источнике две записи с одинаковым `id` и разным `marital_status`... Кстати, ```UPDATE `id` = VALUES(`id`)``` можно убрать как не имеющее смысла.

Comment: т.е. из-за того, что `в обеих таблицах id является первичным ключом`(с) высказывание `В ODKU нельзя ссылаться на поля таблицы-источника - они уже недоступны` (с) - становится некорректным? или я еще что-то недопонимаю

Comment: @SimplyOne Поковырялся - всё-таки можно. Таблица-источник (вернее, её текущая запись, используемая для обновления, одна-единственная) всё же доступна.